# Is believing that God, Israel, and Torah are one Avodah Zarah?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, avodah-zarah, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, zohar

[The Zohar said that God, Israel, and Torah are one.](http://www.thejewishweek.com/jewish_life/sabbath_week/unity_god_torah_and_israel)

I thought Judaism is strictly monotheistic. When Jesus said, "I and the father is one", he was being a heretic. So how come the Zohar includes even more things as God and is not considered to be committing idolatry?

I thought Torah is just one of God's creations (or even man's creation). And Jews are surely not divine.

So what's the meaning? Are we all part of God? In what cases can we call something "one" with God and not be committing idolatry and in what ways we do it and thereby commit idolatry?

Comment: I think that part of your difficulty comes from the summary R. Riskin presents. Something written in the Zohar must be explored and not taken as a singular and simple statement with a clear meaning. Look at the last paragraph of the article and you will see a different presentation of the idea.

Comment: Not everyone believes in the Zohar. And some even believe it to be avodho zoro, like me :)

Comment: @Mori Misplaced modifyer!

Comment: I know zohar is some jewish sect. Seems pretty mainstream. Yap, jewish. Not christianity, not muslims, not those other heretical goyim. So why does it say God is one with this and that?

Comment: This statement does not appear anywhere in the Zohar (or Ra'aya Mehemna, Tikkunei Zohar, etc.).

Comment: Kabbalah in general tries to split God up. Here's a quote from the Rivash, "Kabbalah was 'worse than Christianity', as it made God into 10, not just 3."

Comment: That's a pretty inaccurate quotation.

Comment: I'd wager that if someone were to understand that which you have misinterpreted of what R' Riskin poorly summarized as the literal truth, then that would be shittuf.

Comment: @paquda It would seem not. However, this idea is replete throughout kabbala and chassidus, (according to google and hebrewbooks) so the question is still good.

Comment: @JimThio `I know zohar is some jewish sect. Seems pretty mainstream. Yap, jewish... So why does it say God is one with this and that` 1. Its a book; not a sect. 2. Judasim existed for thousands of years before it. 3. The Bible and prophets didn't know of it. The Talmud didn't know of it. Its popularity exploded only in the last 600 years, and it faced heavy criticism from its publication to today. A classic argument against it is that it represents a dualistic godhead, so it is a pretty poor proof for Judaism view on this. 4. An actual citation would strengthen the question.

Comment: Holy Zohar (III 273A).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please learn chapters 4 and 23 of Likutei Amarim Tanya for deeper understanding. However on the simple level it means that they are connected very strongly with each other -through a Jew learning Torah and doing Mitzvos (which are the Rotzon/will of Hashem Yisborach, which is how Torah is very connected to Him) the Jew becomes connected to Hashem. When a person does something against the Torah he Severs (to a degree) his 'connection'.

It does NOT mean we Daven/pray to the Torah or we Daven to another Jew.

Comment: The issue is shittuf not davening

Comment: Would you say it is similar to a loving married couple saying they are one person? Meaning it's totally metaphorical yet expresses a deep bond?

Comment: @Double AA It is not Shituf at all. Shituf means considering something as in par with G-d no one is saying that the Torah or Jews are in par with G-d.

Comment: @Seth J 100% you hit the nail on its head!

Comment: I didn't say it was or wasn't only that you didn't address the main issue explicitly in your post

Comment: @Double AA fine, but I thought the word 'connected' took care of that.

Comment: Ah I see. That they are interrelated. Perhaps, it's also what Jesus really mean when he said he is one with God. The gentiles then interpret it differently.

Answer (score 7):

Rambam writes ([Hil. Yesodei ha-Torah 2:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904962/jewish/Chapter-Two.htm)):

> He is the Knower, He is the Subject of Knowledge, and He is the Knowledge itself." All is one.

Now, you could ask the same question on him: since G-d is one, then how can we describe Him by these different terms? Indeed, for this reason Maharal ([Gevuros Hashem, 2nd introduction](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14204&pgnum=11)) says that we can't even speak of G-d's knowledge, because He is beyond that or any other description.

R. Schneur Zalman of Liadi points out repeatedly in Tanya (part 1 chs. 2 and 48, part 2 ch. 9, et al) that in fact both perspectives are correct. Hashem Himself is, as Maharal says, completely indescribable; but once G-dliness is "compressed" into the world of Atzilus and the lower worlds, then it is possible to speak of G-d's "knowledge" and of that being one with Him, since it is one of the modes in which He expresses Himself to us created beings.

Torah is G-d's "will and wisdom," and it remains so even in the form in which we study it, in which it largely deals with physical objects (Tanya, part 1, chs. 4-5). The Jewish soul, too, comes from Hashem's attribute of wisdom - anthropomorphically, as a child is engendered from its father's brain (ibid., ch. 2). Thus, both Torah and the Jew are a part of G-d's wisdom - which, as per Rambam's statement, is one with G-d Himself.

(Based on a [letter by R. Yosef Yitzchak Schneersohn](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19787&pgnum=88), originally published in Kitzurim ve-He'aros)

Comment: What is "the Jewish soul"?

Comment: Are you saying that the Torah, the "Jewish soul", and the sefira of chochma are the same thing?

Comment: and non jewish soul is not part of God's wisdom? So a jewish atheist/rapists/etc. is one with God but a lowly goyim like me is not? (just kidding, but you got the point?)

Comment: @DoubleAA: "the Jewish soul" means just that - the nefesh ha-Elokis ("G-dly soul"), which is unique to Jews. At the level that we're familiar with (the world of Asiyah), each of these three appears to be something else; but the point of "they are all one" is that at a higher level - specifically, in Atzilus, the highest of the four spiritual realms - they are one and the same. (And higher than that - before tzimtzum - none of those entities can even be said to exist; to use RSZ's metaphor, they are like "the rays of the sun while they are still in the sun-globe.")

Comment: @JimThio: no need to kid. Jews and non-Jews alike have a nefesh ha-bahamis ("animal soul"), which naturally gravitates towards personal satisfaction. (It can be trained to look beyond the self, but of course that takes a lot of work.) Obviously, in the case of a Jewish criminal, his or her nefesh ha-bahamis is still in that "animalistic" state. But they also have a nefesh ha-Elokis (which I mentioned in my previous comment), which naturally trends to G-d and seeks closeness to Him...

Comment: ...When a Jew sins, then as RSZ puts it, the nefesh ha-Elokis is dragged into it against its will, but still remains faithful to G-d, and will try to do whatever it can to influence the nefesh ha-bahamis. A non-Jew doesn't have a nefesh ha-Elokis, but he or she can - and is expected to - harness the powers of the nefesh ha-bahamis to do good (at the very least, to realize that helping another person helps oneself as well), like taming an animal and using it for work.

Comment: OK I just didn't know if you meant a soul of collective Jewry or the collected souls of Jews. It sounds like the latter. (Also, I'm not getting the feeling RSZ understood much about Solar Physics :) )

Comment: I suppose a neuro scanner would confirm your theory Alex. I saw jews to be about just as good as anyone. Maybe slightly more, but not by much.

Comment: @JimThio: There is source in the Zohar Chadash that says that non-Jews who abandon idolatry and return to the service of God receive a new nefesh and ruach. As for the Jews being the best people, I also struggle with, because I have come across some downright lowly Jews, but most I believe have good hearts (some deeper down than others) and would die for their faith and their people. The Maharal says that Jews fall lower than gentiles because Satan fights us more because of our great potential.

Answer (score 1):

Christianity says the father son and holy ghost are One. Capital O.
Judaism says G-d Israel and the Torah are one. Lower case o.

While the biggest conversation regarding christianity and idolatry focuses on the trilogy, the idea that the devil is a fallen angel that rebelled against their god and has dominion of some area outside of their gods dominion and is in some kind of contest with god, having powers outside of gods, this is 100% idolatry with no allowances of possible partnerships or anything the like.