# His Torah is He?

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries

Within a book which translates some of the works of [Menachem Nachum of Chernobyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Nachum_Twersky) called: ['Upright practices; The light of the eyes'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0809123746)*  I found a quote but without a source:

> He is His Torah and His Torah is He

Where does this quote comes from?

---

* *(Based on the Amazon free preview [It is hard to tell for sure because page 24 and 25 are missing in the preview], it appears this is a translation of the section of Bereshit of R' Menachem Nachum's Meor Eynaim, and part of Sefer Hanhagot Yesharot, which, if it is [this Sefer](https://books.google.co.cr/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA.html?id=F7dONQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y), is a collection of some of the teaching of some of the students of the Baal Shem Tov, including R' Menachem Nachum)*

Comment: If you know (from Nachum) which "he" the quotation refers to, editing that info into your question may improve people's chances of being able to answer it.

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29745/is-believing-that-god-israel-and-torah-are-one-avodah-zarah